# How to set configuration or server to upload image in FCKeditor based on ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fckeditor

I am using FCKeditor as web editor in my asp.net mvc beta application.

I inserted FCKeditor in Create.aspx page and every function of FCKeditors works well except image file uploading from my local pc :(

I changed some configuration as [FCKeditor's document](http://docs.fckeditor.net/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Built_in_File_Browser)

Here's I changed,

fckconfig.js

```
var _FileBrowserLanguage    = 'aspx' ;  // asp | aspx | cfm | lasso | perl | php | py
var _QuickUploadLanguage    = 'aspx' ;  // asp | aspx | cfm | lasso | perl | php | py
```

config.ascx

```
Enabled = true;
```

I made folder named 'userfiles' with access role as everything for ASPNET user.

'userfiles' folder is located in `MyAppRoot/userfiles and MyAppRoot/Views/userfiles`.

Then, I tried to upload image file in the image file browser, but there is no response.

Do I need something to config more?

Answer (score 4):

Oooops, I forgot refer the file for .Net [FredCK.FCKeditorV2](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=75348&package_id=137125) :)

It works fine.