# Retrieve uploaded image from FCK Editor and insert into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, fckeditor

The image uploaded using FCKEditor control
has to be inserted into database. Anyone please help
in how to get the image uploaded using FCK Editor 
control('image' button). The user should also be able to
directly upload image from their local computer without 
uploading it to the server. The image choosen should be 
inserted into database directly. I have writtern function
to insert image into database but do not know how to 
get the choosen image from FCKEditor control!

Comment: make it easy and make uplander for your asp page to your database.

Comment: this link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484951/having-problems-getting-images-to-display-within-fckeditor-within-asp-net-website

Comment: @HAJJAJ: Using a separate uploader control for image uploading will not server our purpose because the user cannot upload image at specific places in between the content added!

Comment: @Geek: We have already implemented the functionality described in the link that you gave, I want to retrieve the image uploaded and save it to our database instead of storing in our application folder. Because as the number of image increase, managing images becomes hard and also increases application size in the server since images are stored in websites local folder in the server!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with this trick

- Step 1 : first save Image in folder
- Step 2 : then find all image tag in FCKeditor's content with XPath you can use htmlAgility for that
- Step 3 : find image path from it and pick Image from folder convert into bytes and save to DB and delete that Image from folder
- Step 4 : replace Image src's value from your Httphandlors path (for showing image)

Comment: But when uploading bigger images(>2MB), image does not get uploaded to FCKEditor folder! The browser hangs up and image does not get uploaded even after 15 mins. How to prevent this? We cannot restrict our business users to upload images of size lesser <2KB because they even upload map images which generally are huge!

Comment: Is it possible to directly insert image into database instead of uploading it to the server and then inserting images finally while saving the content?

Comment: Please check this link http://www.codingbeaver.com/blog/index.php/2009/06/03/how-to-use-the-save-icon-in-fckeditor-to-save-fckeditor-content-on-the-server-side-in-aspnet/  They have given server side code to save content in database in page laod event when 'save' button in FCKEditor control is clicked. I want to know whether this it is possible to invoke server side function while uploading images also.

Comment: @Govind: +1 for your wise solution. Thank you!

Comment: When u click on image icon it open the pop window and it is different page u cant handle event of that page on your page. and this article shows only the save content which is only html. if u want to do that so u have to find that page which upload image from FCKeditors folder and then edit that page according your requirements.