# Regarding CMS concept and html editor in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

we create page through html editor in CMS project. when we design pages then we can add image through html editor. so i just want to know how automatically image path will be stored in my database table and image will upload in proper forlder. suppose i work with fckeditor.

fckeditor can automatically upload images in right folder and how images path will be saved in right table. do i need to parse the html and extract images and replace the image path with properly and atlast upload images programatically to right folder on server before saving the html to databased. please discuss this in detail because i never work with CMS before.

what is the best html editor for CMS and asp.net project.
also tell me what the best free open source CMS for asp.net.

thanks.

Comment: this question can solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802912/retrieve-uploaded-image-from-fck-editor-and-insert-into-database/5803234#5803234